# How to compare aggregated parts of the pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to compare parts of columns in the pandas Dataframe? I have the following Dataframe example, in it there are 4 languages saved (en, de, nl, ua) and each language is supposed to have the same keys/same amount of keys, but with different values (leaving the static column in there for completion, since I do have a static column whose values always stay the same).

```
static  │ langs   │ keys   │ values

x       │ en      │ key_1  │ value_en_1
x       │ en      │ key_2  │ value_en_2
x       │ en      │ key_3  │ value_en_3
x       │ de      │ key_1  │ value_de_1
x       │ de      │ key_2  │ value_de_2
x       │ de      │ key_3  │ value_de_3
x       │ nl      │ key_1  │ value_nl_1
x       │ nl      │ key_2  │ value_nl_2
x       │ ua      │ key_1  │ value_ua_1
```

I need to check what keys and how many are missing per language in comparison to the English one ('en' here), so something like this would be a desired output:

```
│ Lang │ Static   │ # Missing │ Keys          │ 
│ de   │ x        │ 0         │               │ 
│ nl   │ x        │ 1         │ key_3         │ 
│ ua   │ x        │ 2         │ key_2, key_3  │
```

This is my current progress:

```
import pandas as pd

# this is read from a csv, but I'll leave it as list of lists for simplicity
rows = [
    ['x', 'en', 'key_1', 'value_en_1'],
    ['x', 'en', 'key_2', 'value_en_2'],
    ['x', 'en', 'key_3', 'value_en_3'],
    ['x', 'de', 'key_1', 'value_de_1'],
    ['x', 'de', 'key_2', 'value_de_2'],
    ['x', 'de', 'key_3', 'value_de_3'],
    ['x', 'nl', 'key_1', 'value_nl_1'],
    ['x', 'nl', 'key_2', 'value_nl_2'],
    ['x', 'ua', 'key_1', 'value_en_1']
]

# create DataFrame out of rows of data
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["static", "language", "keys", "values"])
# print out DataFrame
print("Dataframe: ", df)

# first group by language and the static column
df_grp = df.groupby(["static", "language"])

# try to sum the number of keys and values per each language
df_summ = df_grp.agg(["count"])

# print out the sums
print()
print(df_summ)

# how to compare?
# how to get the keys?
```

This is the output of the df_summ:

```
                 keys values
                count  count
static language             
x      de           3      3
       en           3      3
       nl           2      2
       ua           1      1
```

At this point I don't know how to proceed. I am grateful for any help/tips.

P.S. This is on Python 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

```
#get set per groups by static and language
a = df.groupby(["static",'language'])['keys'].apply(set).reset_index()
#filter only en language per group by static and create set
b = df[df['language'] == 'en'].groupby("static")['keys'].apply(set)
#subtract mapped set b and join
c = (a['static'].map(b) -  a['keys']).str.join(', ').rename('Keys')
#substract lengths
m = (a['static'].map(b).str.len() - a['keys'].str.len()).rename('Missing')

df = pd.concat([a[['static','language']], m, c], axis=1)
print (df)
  static language  Missing          Keys
0      x       de        0              
1      x       en        0              
2      x       nl        1         key_3
3      x       ua        2  key_3, key_2
```

EDIT:

I try change data:

```
rows = [
    ['x', 'en', 'key_1', 'value_en_1'],
    ['x', 'en', 'key_2', 'value_en_2'],
    ['x', 'en', 'key_3', 'value_en_3'],
    ['x', 'de', 'key_1', 'value_de_1'],
    ['x', 'de', 'key_2', 'value_de_2'],
    ['x', 'de', 'key_3', 'value_de_3'],
    ['x', 'nl', 'key_1', 'value_nl_1'],
    ['x', 'nl', 'key_2', 'value_nl_2'],
    ['x', 'ua', 'key_1', 'value_en_1'],
    ['y', 'en', 'key_1', 'value_en_1'],
    ['y', 'en', 'key_2', 'value_en_2'],
    ['y', 'de', 'key_4', 'value_en_3'],
    ['y', 'de', 'key_1', 'value_de_1'],
    ['y', 'de', 'key_2', 'value_de_2'],
    ['y', 'de', 'key_3', 'value_de_3'],
    ['y', 'de', 'key_5', 'value_nl_1'],
    ['y', 'nl', 'key_2', 'value_nl_2'],
    ['y', 'ua', 'key_1', 'value_en_1']
]

# create DataFrame out of rows of data
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["static", "language", "keys", "values"])
# print out DataFrame
#print(df)
```

and output is:

```
print (df)
  static language  Missing          Keys
0      x       de        0              
1      x       en        0              
2      x       nl        1         key_3
3      x       ua        2  key_3, key_2
4      y       de       -3              
5      y       en        0              
6      y       nl        1         key_1
7      y       ua        1         key_2
```

Problem is for `de` for `y` static there is more keys as in en language.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. The second solution seems to have more complexity to it, is there any reason I would prefer it over the first one?

Comment: I think in large data second can be faster, if only some missing categories.

Comment: Thanks, another question. Where does it compare the other languages to the English one? I think in your solution, if say, German language has more keys than the English one, then the English one will show up as missing one key, right?

Comment: No, it compare all values together. If create `a` then all missing categories create `NaN`s values. Do you need compare only with `english` ?

Comment: i see it in your question. I am going rebuild answer.

Comment: Yes, I need to compare it to English. Would that require a lot of rework? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I dont know.  Give me some time.

Comment: I add solution, please check it.

Comment: Uff, actually, just tried on a much bigger example, I am getting negative values on the "Missing" column for some reason, and the missing keys are actually not missing. I'll try to post an example.

Comment: I think there is problem your en sample per group contains less values as another languages. So get negative numbers.

Comment: I add sample with demonstarte it.

Answer (score 1):

You can first create the missing column by grouping and counting the number of nans. Then create the keys column and add the static column.

```
df2 = (
    df.groupby('langs')['keys'].apply(lambda x: x.values)
      .apply(pd.Series)
      .assign(Missing=lambda x: x.isnull().sum(axis=1))
)

(
    df2[['Missing']].assign(static=df.static.iloc[0],
                            Keys=df2.apply(lambda x: ','.join(df2.loc['en'].loc[x.isnull()]),axis=1))    
)

Out[44]: 
       Missing         Keys static
langs                             
de           0                   x
en           0                   x
nl           1        key_3      x
ua           2  key_2,key_3      x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# First we group with `language` and aggregate `static` with `min` (it's always the same anyway)
# and `keys` with a lambda function that creates a `set`.
In [2]: grouped = df.groupby('language').agg({'static': 'min', 'keys': lambda x: set(x)})

# Then we get the missing keys...
In [3]: missing = (grouped['keys']['en'] - grouped['keys'])

# ... and count them
In [4]: missing_counts = missing.apply(len).rename('# Missing')

# Then we join all of this together and replace the keys with a joined string.
In [5]: grouped.drop('keys', axis=1).join(missing_counts).join(missing.apply(', '.join)).reset_index()
Out[5]:
  language static  # Missing          keys
0       de      x          0
1       en      x          0
2       nl      x          1         key_3
3       ua      x          2  key_2, key_3
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you put the `R` tag in your question, here's how to do it with `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  complete(nesting(static, langs), keys) %>%
  group_by(langs)%>%
  summarise(Static=max(static),
            Missing=sum(is.na(values)),
            Keys=toString(keys[is.na(values)])
            )

  langs Static Missing         Keys
  <chr>  <chr>   <int>        <chr>
1    de      x       0             
2    en      x       0             
3    nl      x       1        key_3
4    ua      x       2 key_2, key_3
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text="static   langs    keys    values
'x' 'en' 'key_1' 'value_en_1'
'x' 'en' 'key_2' 'value_en_2'
'x' 'en' 'key_3' 'value_en_3'
'x' 'de' 'key_1' 'value_de_1'
'x' 'de' 'key_2' 'value_de_2'
'x' 'de' 'key_3' 'value_de_3'
'x' 'nl' 'key_1' 'value_nl_1'
'x' 'nl' 'key_2' 'value_nl_2'
'x' 'ua' 'key_1' 'value_en_1'",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I am also learning dplyr on the side and I understand pandas was built based on R.